# Difference between weighting and replicating observations in linear regression

Tags: mixed-model, predictive-models, model-comparison, weighted-regression

I have a model in which each case is summary statistic of many observations.

I am using a mixed effect model (`lmer()` in R) for prediction and I thought to give more importance to the cases which include more observation.

I tried this either by weighting the model for the number of observations in each case or by replicating in the dataset the cases by the number of observations.

What I didn't expect was that the replicated cases model has a smaller prediction error than the weighted one:

```
Replicated cases model:
    cor misclass  rmse    mae r.squared adj.r.squared   aic   bic logLik LRT
1 0.951       -- 0.145 0.0708     0.952         0.952 -4660 -4540   2350  --

Weighted model:
    cor misclass  rmse   mae r.squared adj.r.squared  aic  bic logLik LRT
1 0.884       -- 0.395 0.206     0.952         0.843 50.1 71.3  -7.04  --
```

(results are from a function I made to evaluate models)

Why is the replicated model giving less prediction error? Which one should I use and why?